# How to transparent mask in fabricJS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, html5-canvas, fabricjs

I need to remove mask before it got saved. How to transparent mask?

Here is the save function.

```
    $(document).on('click','#btn-save-canvas', function(event) {


    if (!fabric.Canvas.supports('toDataURL')) {
      alert('This browser doesn\'t provide means to serialize canvas to an image');
    }
    else {
        canvas.overlayImage.filters = [];
        canvas.overlayImage.applyFilters();
        canvas.renderAll();
        var multi = maskOriWidth/maskWidth;     // Set to original scale

        window.open(canvas.toDataURL({
          format: 'png',
          multiplier: multi,
          left: (canvas.width - maskWidth)/2,
          height: maskOriHeight/multi,
          width: maskOriWidth/multi
        }));
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this can be done by setting `opacity` to `0`. To restore opacity you can set `opacity` as `1` as follows.

```
$(document).on('click','#btn-save-canvas', function(event) {


if (!fabric.Canvas.supports('toDataURL')) {
  alert('This browser doesn\'t provide means to serialize canvas to an image');
}
else {
    canvas.overlayImage.filters = [];
    canvas.overlayImage.applyFilters();
    mask.opacity = 0;
    canvas.renderAll();
    var multi = maskOriWidth/maskWidth;     // Set to original scale

    window.open(canvas.toDataURL({
      format: 'png',
      multiplier: multi,
      left: (canvas.width - maskWidth)/2,
      height: maskOriHeight/multi,
      width: maskOriWidth/multi
    }));
    mask.opacity = 1;   //Show mask
    canvas.renderAll();
}
});
```